# Java efficiently store large amount of sorted data

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, set

Normally when I want to store large amounts of data in java I use a `Set<String>`, which is very fast and efficient.

```
 Set<String> example = new HashSet<String>();
```

But the problem is it can't be sorted. I can't use `Lists` because I'm storing a very large amount of data (100,000s), and using a `List` would heavily impact my programs performance.

```
ArrayList<String> example = new ArrayList<String>()
```

Is there another way of doing it? I need to sort my data (by say date) and new elements are continuously being added to the `List`.

Comment: Does the data structure need to be dynamic? Or can a maximum number of elements be assumed? If so, a simple array could do the trick.

Comment: It needs to be dynamic Im afraid.

Comment: Have a look into `TreeSet`.

Comment: Why storing 100 000 strings in list affects your program perfomance and storing them in set does not? Do you need a fast check that string exists in collection? What other operations are u interested?

Comment: Yea I have to then access all that information performing checks

Comment: Unless you *clearly* describe the critical usage patterns (and constraints) for your data structure, we cannot give you any worthwhile advice.

Comment: Ill have to compare the data that is in this datalist to another Set<String>. Each element of this datalist will need to be checked against another.

Comment: That not a clear description.

Comment: So if I understand you well, you will have two different Sets of Strings and will afterwards iterate over both, comparing each element. 
Sounds like the merge step of mergesort to me.
Since you asked for a dynamic container, I too suggest an ArrayList. Maybe you can make assumptions on how the lists grow. This would greatly improve your performance

Comment: 100,000 is NOT very large... it's rather normal. It's probably just that you're doing strange things with it. You'd better ask what you [really need](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155925) as saying that Set is faster than List just makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can use TreeSet which is an implementation of Set
It orders elements using their comparable natural ordering or by given comparator.

Set example = new TreeSet();

Check api [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use TreeSet! Use TreeSet and add values one by one. When you get values, It will give you sorted values of your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to hold the data in sorted form, then the most efficient solution is:

1. Load the data into an `ArrayList`.
2. Copy to an array.
3. Use `Arrays.sort` to sort the array.
4. To search, use "binary search" which is `O(logN)`.

If you want to be able to build intersperse building and searching, then use a TreeSet.  This uses more memory, but for an incrementally built collection it will be faster, and search performance will be roughly the same.